# Meaning of mpi and openMP execution times

Tags: mpi, openmp

I have a cluster made up of 4 nodes, where each node has 2 processors, and each processor has 8 cores, for a total of 16 cores per machine. I have this application made in two versions one in mpi and the other in openMP for image convolution. When I run the mpi program with 1-2-4-8-12 and 16 cores on the cluster I get the following execution times in seconds:

```
1 core 9.4
2 cores 4.95
4 cores 2.55
8 cores 1.4
12 cores 0.91
16 cores 0.72
```

instead when I run the openMP code with two threads I get the following execution times:

```
1 core 4.95
2 cores 2.65
4 cores 1.33
8 cores 0.68
12 cores 0.77
16 cores 0.64
```

when I always run it with openMP with 4 threads I have the following execution times:

```
1 core 2.64
2 cores 1.37
4 cores 0.80
8 cores 0.66
12 cores 0.86
16 cores 1.10
```

what i can't figure out why with 2 threads as the number of processors increases the time decreases, except in the case with 12 cores. Instead in the case with 4 threads up to 8 cores the times decrease, from 8 cores onwards the times start to increase. Is there anyone who can give me an explanation of these execution times? Particularly:

1. because in the case with 2 threads I get a higher time than with 8 cores and 16 cores
2. why in the case with 4 threads do the times increase from 8 cores onwards?

Thanks to whoever will answer.

Comment: At some point the overheads just start to dominate, so "2." isn't surprising at all, at least for "strong scaling". Do you take care of NUMA regions via placing and binding threads to them?

Comment: No, i don't take care with NUMA regions

Comment: This needs more details. 1. More details needed about the appication. 2. Do you set`OMP_PROC_BIND`? 3. OpenMP only uses one node, right? 4. How do you do you 16 core MPI run? 2 cores per node? 5. Have you tried scaling up your data size? Maybe your problem is too small.

Comment: Hi Victor, the application I've been considering can be found [here](https://github.com/jimouris/parallel-convolution). No I have not set OMP_PROC_BIND but I have set OMP_NUM_THREADS. OpenMP is followed on all 4 nodes as I have set the machine file with the nodes present on the cluster. In order to execute the MPI code I used the following line of code varying np from 1 to 16: 'mpirun -nolocal -machinefile machine_file.txt -np 16 /home...'. Instead to run the code in openMP I used the following line of code: 'mpirun -nolocal -machinefile machine_file.txt -np 4 -x OMP_NUM_THREADS /home...'

Comment: Do the processors have 8 physical cores, or 4 physical/8 logical (hyperthreading) ?

Comment: Have 8 physical cores, and on some it is enabled hyperthreading